# How to examine required libraries?

Tags: java

I developing a web application with a lot of libraries like, Spring, Apache CXF, Hibernate, Apache Axis, Apache Common and so one. Each of these framework comes with a lot of *.jar libraries.

For development I simple take all of the delivered libraries and add them to my classpath.

For deployment not all of these libraries are required, so is there a quick way to examine all the required libraries (*.jar) which are used by my source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move your project to use Maven such things become easier:

```
mvn dependency:analyze 
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does Maven resolve dependencies stemming from programmatic loading of classes?  I'm guessing it doesn't.  Not to detract from your answer- I'm sure its a great time saver.  I'm just saying...there's no real substitute for reading the docs of the third-party libraries you're using.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, Maven + IDE + nice dependency diagrams could help allot.

[See an example of this](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/05/maven-dependencies-diagram/) : it's much easier this way to figure out what happens in a project, and this way you don't need to add to your project "all delivered libraries" - just what it's required.

Answer (score 0):

> [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) traverses Java class file
>   directories and generates design
>   quality metrics for each Java package.
>   JDepend allows you to automatically
>   measure the quality of a design in
>   terms of its extensibility,
>   reusability, and maintainability to
>   **manage package dependencies
>   effectively**.

Answer (score 0):

So, as a quick, dirty, and potentially inefficient way, you can try this in Eclipse:

1. Create two copies of your project.
2. In project copy #2 remove all the jars from the classpath.
3. Pick a source file that now has errors because it can't resolve a class reference.  Pick one of the unresolved classes and note its fully qualified class name.
4. Do Control-Shift-T and locate the unresolved class.  You should be able to see which jar its contained in since all the jars are still in the classpath for project copy #1.
5. Add the jar that contains this unresolved class back into your classpath in project copy #2, then repeat steps 3 and 4 until all class references are resolved.

Unfortunately you're not done yet since the jar files themselves may also have dependencies.  Two ways to deal with this:

1. Go read the documentation for all the third-party packages you're using.  Each package should tell you what its dependencies are.
2. Run your application and see if you get any ClassNotFoundExceptions.  If you do, then use Control-Shift-T to figure out what jar that class comes from and add it to your classpath.  Repeat until your project runs without throwing any ClassNotFoundExceptions.

The problem with #2 is that you don't really *know* you've resolved all the dependencies since you can't simulate every possible execution path your project might take.